# Distance between the point $(1,2,3)$ and the plane $-x+2y+3z+1=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality

I'm trying to find the distance between the point $(1,2,3)$ and the plane $-x+2y+3z+1=0$.

I've used a formula to find this directly and got an answer I believe to be correct ($13/\sqrt{14}$).
However, when attempting to solve this manually through finding the point on the plane closest to the other point (where the plane is orthogonal to the point), and then computing the distance between points I cannot get the same answer (I instead got $4.677072$).

Would someone be able to help me work through the steps of how to find the closest point, and then the distance to help me verify my solutions? Thank you.

My working for the second case:  I took a normal vector of $n=(-1,2,3)$ and from there assumed that I could calculate the nearest point on the plane as $(1-1 \lambda)+(2+2\lambda)+(3+3\lambda)=6+4\lambda$.

From there I took

\begin{align}6+4\lambda&=-1\\
\lambda &= 5/4\\
x&=1-5/4&\hspace{-1em}&=-0.25\\
y&=2+2(5/4)&\hspace{-1em}&=4.5\\
z&=3+3(5/4)&\hspace{-1em}&=6.75
\end{align}

From there I calculated the distance between these points, getting an incorrect solution.

Comment: can you add your solutions? At least the final answer, and adding details of both attempts would be best

Comment: I get $\frac {13}{\sqrt{14}}$, what did you get?

Comment: See my added working @Deepak

Comment: @CalvinKhor I have added working

Comment: @MathsNoob You didn't complete the entire working. But in any case, what is the expected answer? Based on your first method using a "formula"?

Comment: When I used the direct formula I got 13/sqrt{14}$ - however my own solution using this method was way off: 4.677072 @Deepak

Comment: @MathsNoob Thanks that means my method and answer are correct. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your normal vector is correct. But I don't get what you're doing here:

$(1-1 \lambda)+(2+2\lambda)+(3+3\lambda)=6+4\lambda$. (???)

Note that the coordinates of the intersection point of the normal line (that passes through $(1,2,3)$ with the plane) has to satisfy both equation of line and plane. All you have to do is substitute the general coordinates into the equation of the plane and determine your $\lambda$.

Equation of plane is $-x + 2y + 3z + 1 =0$

So you have $-(1-\lambda)+2(2+2\lambda)+3(3+3\lambda)+1 = 0$

Solving, you get $\lambda = -\frac {13}{14}$.

So the point of intersection of that particular normal line with the plane is $(\frac{27}{14},\frac 17, \frac 3{14})$. This is the point on the plane closest to $(1,2,3)$.

Find the distance between that point and $(1,2,3)$. You should get the right answer.

Comment: "So the point of intersection of that particular normal line with the plane is (1/14,1/7,3/14)." Are you sure that's a point on the plane?

Comment: @martingale It was a simple algebraic error. Should be correct now.

Answer (score 2):

The plane is $r\cdot n = -1 $, where $r$ denotes a point on the plane, and a normal vector $n$ is $$n=(-1,2,3).$$

Generally, the $b$ in $r\cdot \frac{n}{|n|} = b$ tells you that the origin is $-b$ units away from the plane. In our specific case, note that the plane equation can be rewritten

$$ r\cdot n=-1\iff (r+\frac{n}{|n|^2})\cdot n=0$$

The (signed) distance $d$ of a point $p=(1,2,3)$ to the plane $r\cdot n=0$ is the projection of $p$ to the line spanned by $n$,

$d = p\cdot \frac{n}{|n|}=\frac{-1+4+9}{\sqrt{14}}=\frac{12}{\sqrt{14}}.$
The distance of $p$ to the plane $r\cdot n=-1$ is therefore $d$ plus the signed normal distance going from $r\cdot n = 0$ to $r\cdot n = -1$, which is $+1/|n|$. Thus the final answer is $$d+\frac1{|n|}=\frac{13}{\sqrt{14}}\approx 3.47.$$

The website Math3d.org lets you graph the objects in question to verify which of your two answers are right. I've drawn the plane, a unit normal $N=(-1,2,3)/\sqrt{14}$, and the normal line passing through $(1,2,3)$:

[image]

If you rotate it just the right way, you can verify the result is indeed somewhere between $3$ and $4$:

[image]

Here's what I made so you can explore it yourself: [(link)](https://www.math3d.org/KwOc6n6Z)

Comment: (and, the closest point is $(1,2,3)-\frac{13}{\sqrt{14}} N = (1,2,3)  -\frac{13}{14} (-1,2,3)=\frac{1}{14}(26,2,3)\approx (1.9,0.1,0.2)$.)

Comment: I think you meant $27$ instead of $26$.

Comment: @Deepak indeed, serves me right for commenting on mobile!

Answer (score 1):

From the equation of the plane, we know the equation of a vector that is perpendicular to the plane - it is given by the coefficients to $x, y, z$. So in this case, $n = (-1, 2, 3)$. From this, we can find the equation of the line passing through $(1, 2, 3)$ that is perpendicular to the plane. From there, calculate where this line intersects the plane, and calculate the distance between that point and (1, 2, 3).

Comment: This is exactly what I've tried, and for some reason it's wrong. Adding my working now.

Comment: I see what you did wrong. The equation of the line gives you expressions for x, y, and z in terms of lambda. So you plug those expressions back into the equation of the plane. You needed to solve the equation -(1-t)+2(2+2t)+3(3+3t)+1=0. I used t instead of lambda here.

Comment: Ah yep, can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Comment: @martingale That "hat" on top of $n$ generally means unit vector. But the normal vector you gave is not a unit vector. Please remove that symbol.